# How to remove side bars of Background Video and fit in full screen

Tags: css

I've been trying to fit the video into the full screen but had no luck. [image] As per pics the video has two (white) pillars (Please click on the picture), the video dimension is 1280x720. I have tried changing the dimension of the video which didn't work. Can anyone help with this, please?

This video is in a section
Below CSS

```
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    filter: brightness(60%);}
```

Comment: can you share your full html and css code this will help you to get the ans fast

Answer (score 0):

remove margin from body and html

```
html, body{
 margin: 0;
}
```

If still doesn't work, then open developers pane in Google Chrome and highlight the white area to see which element is generating the white space.

Comment: Subbies, Thanks for the answer. 
I found the issue which the @media used was wrong. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a margin issue with the video div, or a padding issue with whatever parent div. Link to page?

Comment: Joel, Thanks for the answer. 
I found the issue which the @media used was wrong. 
Thanks